# Magento 2: No Payment Methods showing in Frontend after Ajax call

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I am using IWD One page checkout free extension and Ccavenue online payment method for Magento 2. Site version is 2.1.4 .Initially on checkout page load, both payment methods (COD and Ccavenue)are visible. When entering city,state , "shipping-information" ajax gets fired and both payment methods disappear and "No Payment Method" is shown, but the ajax returns both the payment methods as specified in screen shot.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Console Issue]

[image: Payment Methods in Ajax]

[image]

Comment: Please share this collection.js file

Comment: @kunj: It is core Magento File. Path: Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection.js